# When extending an Activity using NativeScript, where do I define my custom event handlers?

Tags: android, nativescript

This document https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity describes how to extend an activity on Android.

It looks like this code isn't executed directly but provides a skeleton for creation of a Java file.

My question is this:  Where and how do I add custom javascript code for the activity events?  I haven't been able to find any examples of this - or maybe I have but just can't see the custom javascript.